# Vectors in geometry

Tags: geometry, vectors, book-recommendation

How can one use vectors to solve problems in geometry like this one ?

> Prove that the perpendicular bisectors of the sides of a triangle meet at a point.

Any good book recommendations are welcomed.

Comment: The Marsden-Tromba book could help you a Lot.

Comment: Thank you for this information. The book is available on the web. I'll look into it after I download it.

Comment: @SkyWalker If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being in India, I would strongly recommend reading Vectors and Geometry by G S Pandey and R R Sharma. It has very good examples and a strong problem set. It also has a very in-depth approach to basic concepts of geometry using vectors.

As for the question you posed, this has already been [answered on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1735075/prove-that-angle-bisectors-of-a-triangle-are-concurrent-using-vectors).

Comment: Any PDF available for the book you mentioned ?

Comment: @SkyWalker You can get most of the pages on Google Books but I am not aware of a PDF of this as such.

Comment: Thank you for the information.

Comment: @SkyWalker You can accept my answer if it helped you by ticking the green tick mark next to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Perpendicular bisectors at one side represent the loci of the **points at equal distance from the two vertex** of that side, thus the three perpendicular bisectors have to meet each other at the center of the triangle's circumcircle, denoted as **circumcenter**.

Comment: Gimusi. Nice answer.

Comment: Thanks! You can also upvote Peter :)

Comment: Gimusi. +1, you are #1.:)))

Comment: Thanks Peter! Bye.